# where句のエラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql, sql, rails-activerecord

なぜエラーになるのでしょうか？

> ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: near "all": syntax
>   error: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (h >= 0) AND (w >= 0) AND
>   (d >= 0) AND (weight >= 0) AND (all >= 0) ORDER BY "items"."price"
>   ASC):

```
@items = Item.where('h >= ?',height).where('w >= ?',width).where('d >= ?',depth).where('weight >= ?',weight).where('all >= ?',total).order(price: :asc)
```

ここで、

```
.where('all >= ?',total)
```

を省くと、正常に動きます。

データのカラムは以下の通りです。

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.integer :h
      t.integer :w
      t.integer :d

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

と

```
class AddColumnsToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :items, :name, :string
    add_column :items, :price, :integer
    add_column :items, :weight, :integer

  end
end
```

です。どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLがsyntax errorになっているのは、ALLがSQLiteのSQLの予約語だからじゃないかと思います。 他のRDBMSでも予約語だと思います。 (UNION ALLのため

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

```
where("`all` > 0")
```

のようにクオートが必要なんじゃないかと思います。

コマンドラインからはこのように確認できます。

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.24.0 2018-06-04 14:10:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> select * from hoge where all > 0;
Error: near "all": syntax error
sqlite> select * from hoge where `all` > 0;
Error: no such table: hose
```

ただし、allカラムも定義にはないようなので、このままではSQLは失敗するとは思います。

Comment: SQLの予約語だったんですね。回答ありがとうございます。うまく動作しました。